# Google Apps Script - Hangouts chat bot not showing up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps, google-hangouts

I have implemented everything following the Google Apps Script quickstart bot guideline: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot

I have already checked if Hangouts and chatbots are activated within Google Admin / G Suite. Everything is activated.

In addition I have gone through each step of the guideline to check if I did something wrong. But it seems that I have implemented all steps as described.

I can still not find the bot when I try to find it within Google Hangouts.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: I which step of the quickstart are you having trouble?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: https://chat.google.com needs to be uesed instead of https://hangouts.google.com